# First use of $query in Perl IPN sample code causes a "not defined" error

Tags: perl, paypal-ipn

After much research in books and articles about Perl, I have been unable to integrate the Perl IPN sample code into the Perl script for my website. Much of trouble seems to be coming from how certain variables are introduced and used. For example, the first active line of the sample is:

```
read (STDIN, $query, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
```

When this line is compiled, $query is flagged as being undefined so I tried preceding that line with:

```
my $query = "";
```

This caused an uninitialized error. I'm not sure if the context of my script, which is about a dozen other lines of code, is causing the problem or if I'm not understanding Perl variables. Though I've made money coding in about a dozen languages, this is my first Perl script so that's certainly possible.

I start my script with these lines and I'm not sure if they are contributing to the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# This is the Buck A View package.
package BuckAViewMovie;

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use LWP::UserAgent;

print "Content-type: text/html;\n\n";
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to solve these integration problems.

Comment: This is a CGI script, right? You probably don't want LWP, which is a lot like curl. You want CGI, which does what you want to do. LWP is for fetching websites, not making them. Also, you don't want `diagnostics` if you don't know what it does. On the other hand, if this is your first Perl script, thumbs up for the `strict` and `warnings`, well done on that!

Comment: Also, please post the exact error messages.

Comment: @simbabque He wants both `CGI` *and* `LWP::UserAgent` for IPN.

Comment: are you creating a module or and executable? i think you should remove the package declaration if this is a script, or the shebang if this is a module

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [PayPal IPN Perl sample script](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PERL.txt) doesn't properly declare its variables, and therefore won't compile under `use strict`.  Here's a cleaned-up version that ought to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI ();
use LWP::UserAgent;

use constant PAYPAL_URL => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

# read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
my $q = CGI->new();
$q->param( cmd => '_notify-validate' );

# post back to PayPal system to validate
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->post( PAYPAL_URL, scalar $q->Vars );

# assign posted variables to local variables
my $item_name        = $q->param('item_name');
my $item_number      = $q->param('item_number');
my $payment_status   = $q->param('payment_status');
my $payment_amount   = $q->param('mc_gross');
my $payment_currency = $q->param('mc_currency');
my $txn_id           = $q->param('txn_id');
my $receiver_email   = $q->param('receiver_email');
my $payer_email      = $q->param('payer_email');

if ($res->is_error) {
    # HTTP error
}
elsif ($res->content eq 'VERIFIED') {
    # check that $payment_status is 'Completed'
    # check that $txn_id has not been previously processed
    # check that $receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    # check that $payment_amount/$payment_currency are correct
    # process payment
}
elsif ($res->content eq 'INVALID') {
    # log for manual investigation
}
else {
    # error
}

# print result page
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
warningsToBrowser( 1 );
# ...
```

Or you could just use [Business::PayPal::IPN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Business%3a%3aPayPal%3a%3aIPN) like Sinan Ünür suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use PayPal's sample code, you could use  [Business::PayPal::IPN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Business%3a%3aPayPal%3a%3aIPN).

Some time ago, I started writing a replacement [Business::PayPal::IPN::Modern](https://github.com/nanis/Business-PayPal-IPN-Modern), but I never finished it and the code is awful. Plus it doesn't even work in the PayPal sandbox.